# Regex: Ignore whitespace before and after a char

Tags: java, regex

I´m using a regular expression to determine if an '€' is wrongly recognized as an 'e' (For example: Te 23,4 means T€ 23,4 or e23,4 is €23,4 and so on). In my case the expression : `^(T|(?i)(Mio)|(Million)(?-i))?( )?[e]( )?\d*$` works well. BUT there is one case in which my expression doesn´t work. If there is whitespace before AND after the 'e' (" e ") the expression does not work.

How can I expand my expression so that this case will not be considered? I think at least there have to be a character before OR after the 'e' but I dont know how to implement that in my expression.

This regex`(((.)[e])|([e](.)))`works for the whitespace problem, but how can I merge both expressions?

Comment: ( )? is saying you can have an optional whitespace.  You could try just being lazy and having 2 regexes.  ^(T|(?i)(Mio)|(Million)(?-i))?[e]( )?\d*$   and  ^(T|(?i)(Mio)|(Million)(?-i))?( )?[e]\d*$

Comment: Maybe [`(^|T|(?i:Mio|Million))( ?)e( ?)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/1wCKNb/2)? It is difficult to provide a reliable solution because the requirements are not clear.

Comment: @sniperd What a shame ! Sometimes it is so easy ! Thank you !!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution works as well ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, the first alternation group is optional (`?` matches 1 or **0** times), as well as the digit matching part (`*` matches 0 or more chars).

So, the point is to make them obligatory:

```
(^|T|(?i:Mio|Million))( ?)e( ?)\d+
 ^^                             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1wCKNb/2). The `^` is moved to the alternation group (enhanced a bit) and `\d` is quantified with `+` (**1** or more times).

**Details**

- `(^|T|(?i:Mio|Million))` - one of the alternatives:

  - `^` - start of string
  - `T` - a `T`
  - `(?i:Mio|Million)` - a modifier group matching the 2 alternatives in a case insensitive way: `Mio` or `Million`
- `( ?)` - an optional space
- `e` - an `e`
- `( ?)` - an optional space
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: Now I got it :) Thanks a lot !